# Connection reset when large ASCII as UTF-8 msg is sent in an IRC chatroom

Tags: java, sockets, ascii, irc

I'm running a java irc bot for twitch chat. I sometimes receive ASCII art messages that crash the bot. I did a stack trace on it and this is what I'm getting:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at com.ircbot.Bot.InputThread.run(InputThread.java:69)
```

The msg is similar to this: 
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░

On Notepad++ it says length: 943 and ASCI as UTF-8. I'm wondering if the server connection is being closed or the client connection is closing cause of the length of the msg. When I trim the ASCI art down by 4 characters the msg goes through without the Connection being reset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have a gut feeling you got disconnected because of [flooding the channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat_flood). It is quite common at the popular IRC servers to use restrictions like that.

Comment: My bot was randomly disconnecting. After a while I noticed it happened after people posted the ASCII art. I sent my bot to my own private channel and tested it. I didn't need to flood it, just one msg like the one above made the bot disconnect with the following stack trace.

Comment: Oh, ok. And have you tried to experiment with the length of the message? Is'nt one simple char enough to crash your bot?